# Google App Script: Passing value as integer instead of decimal

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a post API payload from Google Script & the number field needs to be passed without decimal values.
However, the app script always adds a decimal 0 (Eg. 1000.0) in the end which creates issues

```
var amt = '1000'; 
Logger.log(amt);
var options = {
    "method": "post",
      "payload": {
  "amount": parseInt(amt),
```

The logger replies with 1000, but when it is used in options, it passes 1000.0

Any help would be useful..

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the detail of specification of API you want to use, for example, in your situation, when you directly use `amt` like `amount": '1000',` as the string, what result did you obtain?

Comment: Again throws up the same error.. ` {"error":{"code":"BAD_REQUEST_ERROR","description":"amount, should be a whole number for e.g. 2234 to create a payment link for 22.34 INR",`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, solved it by the following

```
var amt = parseInt('1000').toFixed(0);
Logger.log(amt);
var options = {
    "method": "post",
      "payload": {
  "amount": amt,
}
     }
Logger.log(options)
```

The toFixed() allows you to fix the integer to any number of decimals you want.

Answer (score 0):

### You could pass the number in your post request as a string and then convert it to an integer on the receiving end

Sample:

*Apps Script*

```js
var amt = '1000'; 
var options = {
    "method": "post",
      "payload": {
        "amount": amt,
       }
     }
```

*Receiving end:*

```js
amt = parseInt(amt);
```

Comment: So important thing is to convert the string to a integer.

Comment: Yes, I tried integer but it is passing as decimal (Eg. 2234.0) while I need it to pass as whole number (2234).. Is there any way?

Comment: An integer is a whole number, do I am wondering if the problem arises at your receiving end AFTER receiving the number as an integer.